# Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static Main Method

Tags: c#, async-await

I realise that this error message is in all fairness pretty self-explanatory.  Given that why does the following console application fail to build citing that error.  Plainly a Main method exists.  Can someone suggest why this might be happening?

[image]

Comment: For one thing, `Main` must return void or int: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs5001

Comment: Marking the `Main` method with the `async` keyword was only introduced in C# 7.1.

Comment: @WaiHaLee, that‘s not entirely true. In C# 7.1 async main methods are a thing and that syntax would be valid.

Comment: @RobP. I had seen the answer you point to and the bit that throws me is that I'm using Visual studio 2017 version 15.5.  In other words this really ought to work according the answer therein.

Answer (score 4):

You must enable C# 7.1 features by going to `Project > Properties > Build > Advanced` and changing it to the appropriate version:

[image: Enable C Sharp 7.1]

You must have at least Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 (version 15.3) for this option to be available.